# How to get "valid"/"invalid" output from a list of letters that will constitute output?

Tags: python

```
fly= input("give me an input")
list=["f","r","u","i","t"]

letter=0
for i in list:
    if i==(fly(letter)):
        print("valid")
        letter +=1
    else:
        print("invalid")
```

The output should show whether the word is valid based on the letters it contains.

I'm fairly new at Python. I would like to find out if the output is valid or not when the input can only be composed of letters "f","r","u","i" and "t" and if another letter is written in input the outcome should be invalid.So any displacement of word fruit is valid but if input is "tfruh" then it should show invalid due to an unwanted letter "h". However not all letters have to be included so input can be "fru" and should be valid. Also how can I find the position of the invalid character and print it?

Comment: Please add the actual code tp your question instead of image. It will help other SO community members to read and run the program and they'll be able to help you more efficiently, without wasting much of their time

Comment: Thank you so much this is my first post I'll be more careful next time! :)

Comment: `fly(letter)` doesn't make much sense. If `fly` were a function, then it would call the function, passing it `letter` as its argument. But in your code `fly` is the name of the string returned by the `input` function. BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficient way to test if a character is valid is to use a set of valid letters. And we can use the built-in `enumerate` function to get the characters in a word and their positions at the same time.

```
allowed = set('fruit')

words = ('fitur', 'iursfgt', 'ffrruuiitt', 'FRUIT')
for word in words:
    print(word)
    valid = True
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c not in allowed:
            print('Bad char', c, 'at position', i)
            valid = False
    if valid:
        print(word, 'is valid\n') 
    else:
        print(word, 'is invalid\n')
```

**output**

```
fitur
fitur is valid

iursfgt
Bad char s at position 3
Bad char g at position 5
iursfgt is invalid

ffrruuiitt
ffrruuiitt is valid

FRUIT
Bad char F at position 0
Bad char R at position 1
Bad char U at position 2
Bad char I at position 3
Bad char T at position 4
FRUIT is invalid
```

---

If you aren't permitted to use `enumerate`, you could do this using indirect iteration, by looping over a `range`, and using that to index into the word. And you don't *need* to use a set for the allowed letters, you can just use a string, or a list.

```
allowed = 'fruit'
words = ('fitur', 'iursfgt', 'ffrruuiitt', 'FRUIT')
for word in words:
    print(word)
    valid = True
    for i in range(len(word)):
        c = word[i]
        if c not in allowed:
            print('Bad char', c, 'at position', i)
            valid = False
    if valid:
        print(word, 'is valid\n') 
    else:
        print(word, 'is invalid\n')
```

This code produces the same output as the earlier version.

---

Just for fun, here's an almost-unreadable version. ;)

```
allowed = set('fruit')
words = ('fitur', 'iursfgt', 'ffrruuiitt', 'FRUIT')
for word in words:
    a = [word]
    a.extend(f'Bad char {c} at position {i}' for i, c in enumerate(word)
        if c not in allowed)
    a.append(f"{word} is {('in', '')[not a]}valid\n")
    print('\n'.join(a))
```

This is definitely **not** a good way to code this!

Comment: Can I find the position of the invalid letter without using the enumarate function and just by using for loop and if statements? So that output should look like this:" X (position 2) is not a valid letter." Btw thank you so much for the solution definitely will try this too!

Comment: @Cabbage55 Yes, you can do it without `enumerate`, but the alternatives aren't as clean. `enumerate` is a very important built-in function, so it's a Good Idea to learn how to use it. Of course, if this is a homework assignment and you aren't allowed to use `enumerate`, then that's a different matter. ;)

Comment: Eg, instead of `enumerate` you could do `for  i in range(len(word):` `c = word[i]` Etc. But using a `for` loop with `range` like that to iterate over a string is considered bad style in Python. It's less efficient, and tends to make the code more cluttered and harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code:

```
fly= input("give me an input ")
mylist=["f","r","u","i","t"]

letter=0
for i in fly:
    if i in mylist:
        print("valid")
        letter +=1
    else:
        print("invalid")
```

For every character in your input, you check if your list of allowed characters contains it.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function like below to check whether your word is a valid word (each character of word is within your list), and break the code with the index of invalid character as (explanation added as the comment to the code):

```
def check_validity(word):
    my_list = ["f", "r", "u", "i", "t"]
    #  ^ don't use `list` as variable name as it is an in-built data type

    # `enumerate` allows to iterate the list returning the index as well  
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        # check character of your string is not in your list
        if c not in my_list:
            print("invalid character '{}'' at index: {}".format(c, i))
            break   # break loop if condition satisfies
    else:
        print("Valid word: {}".format(word))
```

**Sample Run**:

```
>>> check_validity("fruit")
Valid word: fruit
>>> check_validity("itf")
Valid word: itf
>>> check_validity("frugit")
invalid character 'g'' at index: 3
```

Note: I am passing the strings to these functions, but you pass the value returned by `input()` here (in your case, the `fly` variable).

Comment: I've been working on your function for some time and was trying to add some features to it but failed:( For example function gives the first wrong letter that does not belong to the list and I've wanted it to iterate over each letter saying " 'h' at position 4 is invalid  " and should do the same for each next invalid letter so I set i=0 then added + 1 but that only increased the value of the first invalid letter. Can you give me a tip on how to achieve such a function?

Comment: @Cabbage55 So do you mean that you function should print all the invalid character? If yes, then you need to just remove the `break` statement from the function I shared